# c-style of assigning variable in the if-statement for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

in c/c++, I can "assign a value to a variable" in if-statement as follows:

```
   int a;

   if ( (a = foo()) > 0)
   {
      printf("%d\n", a);
   }
```

Is there any equivalent statement for python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really.  In Python, an assignment is a statement, whereas in C it is an expression.  The condition in the if statement must be an expression in both languages.

Comment: I suspect that this design decision was made, in fact, to prevent exactly this kind of construct. I have no source for that though :P

Comment: @detly: Common sense is a good enough source in this case. :)

Comment: @detly: [The effbot knows all](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression.htm) "The reason for not allowing assignment in Python expressions is a common, hard-to-find bug in those other languages"

Answer (score 3):

In Python the assignment in the if condition is forbidden so you end up with a syntax error, this design decision was done to protect against error like this:

in C you can easily do:

```
if (a = 1) {
  ...
}
```

while you mean:

```
if (a == 1) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Doubly so because we don't have compiler warnings in dynamic languages.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this and a good job too. This style of coding leads to complex and hard to read code.

Answer (score 1):

Until today, I believe the answer was no.

I thought that to be unfortunate, so I wrote a little Python module, which I call [`let`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/let/1.0.0), which allows you to do this kind of thing.

Install it like this:

```
pip install let
```

I believe the following will accomplish what you're looking for:

```
from let import let

if let(a = foo()):
    print(a)
```

I dropped the `> 0` from your answer, making the assumption that `foo` will either return `0` or a positive integer. If I'm incorrect and you really do want to check if the return value is greater than 0, then this works too:

```
if let(a = foo()) > 0:
    print(a)
```

`let` also couples well with `while` loops, if you have a function which returns something different each time until eventually it returns something `False`. IE, IBM's DB2 module requires you to repeatedly call a `fetch` method to get each row from the database. You could use `let` to simplify the logic of looping over everything in it like this:

```
while let(result = db.fetch_results()):
    # do whatever with result here
```